# Unable to find elements after switching to iframe in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I'm running a test case and part of it is to check if an element in an `iframe` is visible
I have done the below but it's not working and always goes to the except block. Thank you

```
try:
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.frame("iframe-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    time.sleep(2)
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-11 answer-feedback-label']//div[contains(text(),'Hello World!')]"):
        logging.info("Success")
except:
     logging.error("Failure")
```

Comment: Post the html. You should also remove the `try - except`, you are masking the error message that tells you what is the problem.

Comment: Use "except Exception as e:  print(e)" to print error message.

Answer (score 1):

To check if an element in an `<iframe>` is visible or not, as the the desired element is with in an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()`.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
    .
    .
    .
    try:

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"iframe_XPATH")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-11 answer-feedback-label']//div[contains(text(),'Hello World!')]")))
        logging.info("Success")
    except TimeoutEception:
         logging.error("Failure")
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)